# include exclude filters from a elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I want to know if there is a way to to include or exclude filters when preforming a query. This way I write only one query and not multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with the `filter` tag within your `query`. Something like:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "color": "red"   }},
        { "term": { "brand": "gucci" }}
      ]
    }
  }
```

But then you might want to have a look at [post filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) as well. There could be differences in performance, when you do the filtering within and out of the `query`. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958882/elasticsearch-filtered-query-vs-filter) could be handy. You could use the [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html), when it comes to structured data.